# Execute Command Line In WiX Script?

Tags: visual-studio, wix

How can I execute a command line from within a WiX script?

I want to dynamically generate a command line string and have it executed. I'm not installing a file related to this.

Using version 3.0.5419.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you probably want is something like this (observing quotes where necessary in the command):

```xml
<CustomAction Id='ExecNotepad' Directory='INSTALLDIR' Execute='immediate' 

ExeCommand='[SystemFolder]notepad.exe &quot;[SOMEFILE]&quot;' Return='ignore'/>
```

The ExeCommand is where you want to put your command.  Here I have notepad launching with a file.  Some of the attributes will be different, depending on what your command does - particularly the Execute and Impersonate parameters.  It would also be helpful to know what version of WiX you were using (the code above is v2).

Comment: Here's the page for the CustomAction element for v2:

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm

and v3:

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_customaction.htm

Hope that helps

Comment: I check the documentation of the V3, but I could not find what would be different with your example, did I miss something?

Comment: Edit: Ok, now I understand. There probably wouldn't be a difference in this sample, I just wanted to point to both versions of the documentation because some related stuff is different

BTW, here is the WiX v3 documentation on the new site:

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/events-and-actions/extra-actions/

Note that this is not how I actually do this nowadays, because I want more control over how errors are handled. I have a WiX extension which creates entries in a custom table, and a custom action (part of the same extension) which processes the entries.