# Call command line after installation in Wix

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am using wix and want to call command line after installation.

How can I do this?

My command line is here "bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff" // this makes dep off

Yes, I've read about custom actions, but I didn't see any example with command line.

P.S. bcdedit is usual exe in Win 7 and higher.

P.S. currently I have next script and it does not work:

```
          Directory  ="INSTALLLOCATION"
          ExeCommand ='echo hello> echo_test.txt'
          Execute    ="immediate"
          Return     ="asyncNoWait"
                />
```

Comment: can you give the detail of error and the code you have used

Comment: Ew, changing a global setting of the machine like that is not something an average installation should do. Perhaps this is okay within a company, but if some app did this to my machine I would be unhappy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this example works...

```
<CustomAction Id         ="echo_test"                     
              Directory  ="INSTALLLOCATION"
              ExeCommand ='NOTEPAD.EXE echo_test.txt'
              Execute    ="immediate"
              Return     ="asyncNoWait"
                    />
```

My test example with echo didn't worked for some reason.
And bcdedit does not exist on WinXP, where I am testing now...

Comment: So this code does work, doesn't it? If yes, you should accept it as the answer. And [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609012/call-command-line-after-installation-in-wix/7614565#7614565) explains why it didn't work with `echo`.

Answer (score 11):

`echo` is not an executable, it is the command of the command processor `cmd.exe`. Change your `ExeCommand` value to `cmd.exe /c &quot;echo hello >echo_test.txt&quot;`.

Your `echo_test.txt` would be in an arbitrary directory, you have to use absolute paths to get predictable results.

Answer (score 2):

Hi there are lots of example available on net...

try these links

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/qtexec.htm

[Execute Command Line In WiX Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313545/execute-command-line-in-wix-script)

[WiX - CustomAction ExeCommand - Hide Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372978/wix-customaction-execommand-hide-console)

Or try this example:

```
 <CustomAction Id="SetQtExecCmd" Property="SetQtExec"
       Value="&quot;[PutPathOfThisFileHere]bcdedit.exe&quot; /set {current} nx AlwaysOff" />
<CustomAction Id="SetQtExec" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
```

Comment: it says: Error 2 The CustomAction/@BinaryKey attribute's value, ' ', is not a legal identifier.  Identifiers may contain ASCII characters A-Z, a-z, digits, underscores (_), or periods (.).  Every identifier must begin with either a letter or an underscore.

Its because it is  empty.

Yes, Ive seen those links. And I didn't see any working example for command line, not for single exe.

Comment: yes that is because the **BinaryKey** was empty...i have updated my answer ...check it out

Comment: I've used your example, but for some reasons when I use it, my installation fails. I've found correct answere.

Comment: The first correct answer was from me. But I still need working example for command "bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff>>log.txt"